# Spotify API Currently Playing Device

Tags: spotify

I'm playing around with the spotify API and I want to display the currently playing device. This usually works fine but when I query for devices, sometimes I get more than one device with the IsActive flag set to true.

This happens when I'm using my own account and I have the Spotify Client open on my PC and also on my iPod. The music is playing on my iPod but both my PC and iPod show a value of True for IsActive. Is there a way to check which one is actually currently playing music?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you have a family subscription? That allows up to 5 devices to play simultaneously.

Comment: Nope, certainly don't have a family sub. I can't play on more than one device at once but IsActive returns true for more than one device so I have no visibility of the currently playing device.

Comment: Weird. I just ran a test call from my account, with 2 devices and it returned correct results. Switched playing to mobile device and again got correct results. By IsActive you're refering to `is_active` ? Correct endpoint is `https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/devices`